# Not receiving the data change at LiveData

Tags: android, mvvm, observable, android-livedata

I'm using a simple retrofit call which then updates the data and the fragment observes to it through the view model. 
Unfortunately for some reason it just doesn't work. it's like the "postValue or setValue" don't work or are simply gone.

Fragment:

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(requireActivity()).get(MyViewModel.class);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       ...
        subscribe();
        mViewModel.fetchList();

        return rootView;
    }

    private void subscribe() {
        mViewModel.getListObservable().observe(this, new Observer<List<MyObj>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable List<MyObj> objList) {
                ....
            }
        });
    }
```

MyViewModel:

```
 private LiveData<List<MyObj>> mListObservable = new MutableLiveData<>();

    private Repository repository;

    public MoviesViewModel(Application application) {
        super(application);
        repository = new Repository();
    }

    public void fetchList(){
        mListObservable = repository.getList();
    }

    public LiveData<List<MovieObj>> getListObservable(){
        return mListObservable;
    }
```

Repository:

```
public LiveData<List<MyObj>> getList(){

        final MutableLiveData<List<MovieObj>> data = new MutableLiveData<>();

        mServiceInterface.getData("en-US").enqueue(new Callback<MyResponseCustom>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<MyResponseCustom> call, Response<MyResponseCustom> response) {
                data.postValue(response.body().getResult());
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<MyResponseCustom> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });

        return data;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are post value to `Repository` `MutableLiveData` but observing `MyViewModel` `LiveData`. Merge them or use only one

Try it like this

MyViewModel:

```
public LiveData<List<MyObj>> fetchList(){
   return repository.getList();
}
```

Fragment:

```
mViewModel.fetchList().observe(this, new Observer<List<MyObj>>(){...}
```